# use table from spreadsheet in google-visualization API

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

Ordinarily I have data in a Google Spreadsheet and I want to represent them with google-visualisation API. 
I try to reproduce the code from two examples but I failed. 
Example 1 : the [datatables and dataview docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#query) 
Example 2 : the [how to use google spreadsheets docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#queryurlformat)

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

  function drawBasic() {

    function drawGID() {
    var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B');
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XWJLkAwch5GXAt_7zOFDcg8Wm8Xv29_8PWuuW15qmAE/gviz/tq=' + queryString);
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

      var data = reponse.getDataTable();

      var options = {
        title:'test',       
      }

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data,options)
     }
   }

   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> will it works </h1>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a function `drawGID` wrapping the code and never called,

remove that...

**EDIT**

changed url, using `setQuery` as well,

in addition, found a typo --> `var data = reponse.getDataTable();`

`reponse` should be `response`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawBasic,
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar', 'table']
});

function drawBasic() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FzvV_rh81koInXeZp6LfXmZb6YGwKDB3CU20RdVOfjc/edit#gid=0'
  );
  query.setQuery('SELECT A, B');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var options = {
    title: 'test'
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options)
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks ! the `set.Query` is more readable... sorry for that typo

Comment: cheers! glad to help, i've had trouble with the url -- `setQuery` allows you to copy the same url as when viewing the spreadsheet in a browser...

Comment: just for clarification, `setQuery` isn't needed, unless you need to limit certain columns or rows -- and I added the `'table'` package, so a table chart could be drawn to test the data...

Comment: okay..  so `table` is a kind of help while coding. One thing hard in my little adventure is that I don't have a console (which would have enable me to see the typo error for exampe)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which follow the [quick start example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) inside the google chart API docs. There are other solutions but this one is quite readable. 

Take care to the end of the spreadsheets URL (`edit#gid=0`), and see the [google query langage](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) for the syntax of `query.setQuery`

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']}); 
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XWJLkAwch5GXAt_7zOFDcg8Wm8Xv29_8PWuuW15qmAE/edit#gid=0'
    );
    query.setQuery('SELECT A, B OFFSET 5'); //select specific cells from the table
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
  }

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var options = {
      title: 'glue data from spreadsheet',
      height : 250,
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options)
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```